# ¿cómo evitar eliminar archivo actual al hacer update en un formulario?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

1.- Hago la consulta con un POST id del producto que se quiere editar

```
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id ='$id'";
        $resultado = $conexion->query($query);
        $row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
        ?>
          <label for="product_name">Nombre del producto:</label> <br>
          <input type="text" required name="product_name" value="<?php echo $row['product_name']; ?>">

          <label for="product_img">Imágen del producto</label>
          <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['product_img']); ?>"/>  
          <label>Cambiar Imagen</label>
          <input name="product_img" type="file" value="0" />
          <input type="submit" value="Subir producto editado" />
```

2.- Entonces mi pregunta es, ¿cómo para evitar que la imagen del *file input* que esté vacio no se actualice y borre la imagen que está actualmente?

Agradecimientos anticipados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolví haciendo una comprovación con if y else

```
 if ($img != '') {
   $query = "UPDATE productos SET product_name='$name',product_category='$category',category_two='$category2',product_price='$price',product_description='$description',product_img='$img' WHERE id ='$id'";
    }else{
    $query = "UPDATE productos SET product_name='$name',product_category='$category',category_two='$category2',product_price='$price',product_description='$description' WHERE id ='$id'";
}
```

¿es lo mejor para resolver este problema?

Comment: Un `if` apenas se nota el tiempo de ejecución que tiene, si que es seria posible hacerlo de otra forma pero requeriría el cambio de estructura de la base de datos me imagina. Sinceramente no me parece mala al solución al fin y al cabo es una simple comprobación que te evita el problema y al fin y al cabo una app siempre acabara teniendo cientos de ifs